# Checkbox: Display depending on value of session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a two checkboxes on different pages. I am sending the value from the first checkbox using session like this:

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["VSSsnap"] = CheckBox1.Checked;
            Response.Redirect("~/Addnewpolicy4.aspx");
        }
```

I receive this session like this on the next page:

```
string vss = Session["VSSsnap"].ToString();
```

However, I want to put this value in a checkbox on the second page.

I tried this, but I get an error:

```
CheckBox1.Checked = Session["VSSsnap"].ToString();
```

I also tried this; when I debug, the values are also present (but not displayed by checkbox):

```
CheckBox1.Checked.Equals(Session["VSSsnap"]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code :

```
if( Session["VSSsnap"] != null )
{
 CheckBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["VSSsnap"]);
}
```

Comment: The code will work, but I think Michael or Luke's code is recommended compared to mine.

Answer (score 2):

You are not casting the value from the Session. Try:

```
CheckBox1.Checked =  (bool) (Session["VSSsnap"] ?? false);
```

The ?? check to ensure that if VSSsnap is null for any reason false will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

The `Checked` property of the checkbox is a `bool`, not a `string`.

You're trying to assign a `string` to the `Checked` property which is why you're getting an error.

Try this instead:

```
CheckBox1.Checked = (bool)(Session["VSSsnap"] ?? false);
```